# How to configure playframework server to support ssl

Tags: ssl, https, playframework

How to configure playframework server to support ssl
example
https://localhost:9000

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to use the integrated way, this is described in the [release notes](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/releasenotes-1.1#https) of playframework v1.1. you can then set the port for https in applicaon.conf.

Comment: Since version 1.2.3 you can find it also in documentation: [Put your application in production \ HTTPS configuration](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/production#https)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to run playframework behind an Apache server with ModSSL.

Answer (score 0):

The secure way is to run your application behind a solution that ends the SSL and a firewall that will drop attacks, if you own your equipments and datacenter.

Otherwise you can't analyse traffic to identify attacks : this is the weakness of SSL if you use it until your application server.