# How to config PlayFramework2 to support SSL?

Tags: ssl, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've read
[How to configure playframework server to support ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039012/how-to-configure-playframework-server-to-support-ssl)
and I also tried to follow http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/releasenotes-1.1#https but it doesn't work for me

many thanks~

I read the doc for Play1 because I can't find any more updated information for Play2 about https.

in application.conf, I added these lines:

```
https.port=9443
certificate.key.file=conf/host.key
certificate.file=conf/host.cert
```

I type `run` in the play console, and try to access the server at `https://localhost:9443` the browser timed out without anything logged in the console output

Comment: What doesn't work? Please provide more information like stacktraces and your configuration files. Also you've read the documentation for Play 1 and you are trying to configure SSL for Play 2, so your reading the wrong documentation

Comment: @Li-o I've updated with more information. Do you have an updated documentation for Play2 about https configuration? Could you share that with me~? Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It won't work with the approach you are taking. You are mistaking release notes of 1.x branch with 2.x branch.

**in 1.x branch**, it is possible. Release notes are sufficient, and they worked for me.

**For 2.1+ branch**, please refer to @Christina's comment. Support has been added in 2.1 and the discussion thread provides details.

Quoting James Roper's response

> In dev mode, it's very easy, just:
>
> JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttps.port=9443 play run
>
> Play will generate a private key and self signed certificate, which
>   obviously your browser will balk at with a big red warning.  It will
>   reuse that generated self signed certificate for each subsequent run
>   of Play, so you should only get the browser error once.  Obviously
>   this self signed certificate is probably not what you want in
>   production.  Also important to note is that the self signed
>   certificate generation will only work on JVMs that use the sun
>   security libraries (eg Oracle and OpenJDK, but most notably not IBM
>   J9).  On JVMs that don't use these, you will get a
>   NoClassDefFoundError when it tries to generate the certificate.
>
> In prod (and this config also applies to dev) you configure it much
>   the same way that you configure SSL ordinarily in Java, via system
>   properties.  Here's a summary:
>
> **https.port** - The port that should be used
>
> **https.keyStore** - The path to
>   the keystore containing the private key and certificate, if not
>   provided generates a keystore for you
>
> **https.keyStoreType** - The key
>   store type, defaults to "JKS"
>
> **https.keyStorePassword** - The password,
>   defaults to ""
>
> **https.keyStoreAlgorithm** - The key store algorithm,
>   defaults to the platforms default algorithm
>
> **https.trustStore** - This
>   feature hasn't been fully implemented, currently it will always use
>   the JDKs trust store for verifying client side certificates (which you
>   can of course configure yourself) whether you supply a value for this
>   or not, unless you specify "noCA", in which case, it will use a trust
>   store that trusts all certificates with no validation or verification,
>   which is useful for if using webid client side certificate verification.

**For 2.0 branch**, you have to put another server infront of play i.e either apache/nginx/other which listens on https and forwards the request to play in http.

Instructions to setup a frontend server are available at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/HTTPServer

So run your play server on a port. Have apache forward request from domain.com to 127.0.0.1:9443.

**Sample apache config**

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
  ProxyPreserveHost On
#  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/


  #   SSL Engine Switch:
  #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
  SSLEngine on

  #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
  #   the ssl-cert package. See
  #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
  #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
  #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key


  #   Certificate Authority (CA):
  #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
  #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>

  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Although this was true at the time it was written let me add here that SSL support has been added to Play 2.1 as indicated by [this Google Groups topic](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/FeTUDQwaEPg/discussion).

Comment: If creating an SSL Certificate, i.e. not using the self-signed certificate, must the public key of the created certificate be imported into the Play clients' browsers?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for setting up the current version of Play (2.2.x) is here:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ConfiguringHttps

Answer (score 4):

Right now you seem to need a reverse proxy managing the SSL for you. I found a [ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/215-tls-https-support-in-play-20) and a [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/DvD8iqmIwE4/discussion) discussing this.

Comment: Thanks for the help~ informative read, I'll keep watching the issue~

Answer (score 3):

This is useful for locally testing https:

```
activator "run -Dhttps.port=9005"
```

Then point your browser to `https://localhost:9005`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing we did was to use AWS ELB to handle our SSL, then setup the SSL forwarding (HTTP -> HTTPS) using a plays filters.  The main benefit, takes the SSL load off your server and you don't have to run Apache or Nginx in front of play (as some solution point out).

You can see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23646948/690164

I also write a bit more about it in my blog:
http://www.mentful.com/2014/05/25/play-framework-filter-for-aws-elastic-load-balancer-forward-http-to-https/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using securesocial 3.0.3M. Set

```
securesocial.ssl = true
```

in securesocial.conf and you should be good to go. 
Then restart your sbt or activator with

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttps.port=9443 activator run
```

Go to localhost:9443

enjoy