# play framework2: find out if an app is running on http or https

Tags: url, playframework-2.0, router

I'm trying to find out if a play 2 (with scala) app is running on http or https

I tried with routes.Application.index.absoluteURL(request), like this

```
def chatUri(username: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader): String = {

  val uri = routes.Application.index.absoluteURL(request)
```

but I get the following error:

```
/home/sas/tmp/websocket-chat/app/controllers/Application.scala:51: overloaded method value absoluteURL with alternatives:
[error]   (secure: Boolean)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (play.mvc.Http.Request)java.lang.String
[error]  cannot be applied to (play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)
[error]     val rootUri = Uri(routes.Application.index.absoluteURL(request))
```

I tried to transform the RequestHeader into a Request, but I get the following error

```
val rootUri = Uri(routes.Application.index.absoluteURL(request.asInstanceOf[Request[Any]]))

(secure: Boolean)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (play.mvc.Http.Request)java.lang.String
[error]  cannot be applied to (play.api.mvc.Request[Any])
[error]     val rootUri = Uri(routes.Application.index.absoluteURL(request.asInstanceOf[Request[Any]]))
```

Any idea how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Must say I'm surprised about problems with getting absolute url in Scala, AFAIR in Java it works well, anyway... I doubt if it will help you to determine the protocol (*edit*: as @MariusSoutier wrote)

As there's [no built-in support for SSL](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/-7zP0jV5T4U) in Play 2 most probably you are using (or you should use) some HTTP server on front of your application, let's say Apache. There are some samples and posts describing the proccess:

1. Take a look at topic: [How to config PlayFramework2 to support SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10758612/1066240) Nasir gives there a sample of configuring the Apache as a proxy for Play
2. There's also nice description of [configuring Apache as a proxy](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/08/setting-up-apache-as-a-ssl-front-end-for-play/) (**warning** *the posts describes the Play 1.x, however Apache part will be the same*)
3. Finally you need to to set the [proper headers which will be forwarded](https://serverfault.com/a/257643/118032) to your app

so after setting the headers (as showed in point 3) you'll be able to check it in your controller:

```
def index = Action { request =>
    val proto = request.headers("X-FORWARDED-PROTO")
    Ok("Got request [" + request + "] with schema: " + proto )
}
```

or the same in Java controller:

```
public static Result index() {
    String proto = request().getHeader("X-FORWARDED-PROTO");
    return ok("Got request [" + request() + "] with schema: " + proto);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, by creating an absolute URL, you cannot find out if the app is running on http or https - take a look at the method signature:

```
def absoluteURL (secure: Boolean = false)(implicit request: RequestHeader): String
```

That's right, you have to *tell* this method whether or not you want secure.

I think this is because Play was designed to working behind a reverse proxy which makes it transparent to use encrypted requests. That means Play shouldn't have to care about this. `absoluteURL` can only enforce https URLs, for example to make sure a login page uses https.

Depending on your reverse proxy, you can set a custom http header that tells you what is used. `RequestHeader` doesn't have the information.

Comment: allow me to share a good post talling a workaround for dealing with this affair: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2427