# Enforcing SSL in Play! Framework 2.1.3

Tags: ssl, playframework-2.0

I want to write a small back-end REST server using Play! Framework 2.1.3. This server will only serve WS requests, and all communication to it must be made over SSL. For this reason, I don't want to have an HTTP port open for this server at all.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748305/how-to-config-playframework2-to-support-ssl) question regarding SSL on various Play! branches, and according to the [linked discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/FeTUDQwaEPg/discussion), the only way to open SSL port (which worked for me) is to add JAVA_OPTS before running the server, like so:

JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttps.port=9443 play run

This setting opens both HTTP and HTTPS ports for communication.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to open the server only for SSL communication? How?
2. Is there a configuration file where I put this setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is super easy with Play 2.2, not sure it works on 2.1.3, I didn't see it in the 2.1.x docs...but was in the 2.2.x docs...so give it a shot, it might be implemented.

Throw this in your configuration file :

```
http.port=disabled
```

Or you could run it with the command line option :

```
-Dhttp.port=disabled
```

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ConfiguringHttps

Comment: Yes, I saw it as well - it is not implemented in 2.1.3.